# How to display input text correctly in this code

Tags: css

I am trying to display, inline, the 3rd option "Custom" with some text and input boxes so that it reads.

Custom: I would like [ ] x [ ].

However, the text boxes aren't appearing, presumably because I have a display:hide.

I have tried adding

```
#product .sizes input:not([type:"text"]) 
{
  display: none;
}
```

However, a massive text box appears - so at a loss what to do.
Probably something simple, but I just can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

```css
#product .sizes label{
   position: relative;
   color: #2fcc71;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   text-align: center;
   height: 80px;
   line-height: 80px; 
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
   border: 3px solid #2fcc71;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
#product .sizes label span{
 display: inline-block !important;
   color: #2fcc71;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: 1rem;
   text-align: left;
   height: 10px !important;
   line-height: 10px !important;    
 } 
 
#product .sizes input:checked + label{
   border: 3px solid #333;
   background-color: #2fcc71;
   color: #fff;
 }
 
#product .sizes input:checked + label:after {
   content: "\2713";
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   border-radius: 100%;
   border: 2px solid #333;
   background-color: #2fcc71;
   color: #fff;
   z-index: 999;
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   right: -10px;
 }

#product .sizes input {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="product">
    <section class="sizes">
     <div id="fixedSize"></div>
     <div id="ChooseSize">
      <input type='radio' name='radio_size' id='size1' value='1'><label class='size1-label cell' for='size1'>Standard</label>
      <input type='radio' name='radio_size' id='size2' value='2'><label class='size2-label cell' for='size2'>Different</label>
      <input type='radio' name='radio_size' id='size3' value='3'><label class='size3-label cell' for='size3'>Custom: I would like <input type="size_h"> x <input name="size_w" type="text"></label>
     </div> 
  </section>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, you can quite simply target any inputs inside a label:

```
#product .sizes label > input {
   display: inline;
}
```

Using this selector, you can then style the inputs as you want. Using `width` to control how big the inputs are...

```css
#product .sizes label{
   position: relative;
   color: #2fcc71;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   text-align: center;
   height: 80px;
   line-height: 80px; 
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
   border: 3px solid #2fcc71;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
#product .sizes label span{
 display: inline-block !important;
   color: #2fcc71;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: 1rem;
   text-align: left;
   height: 10px !important;
   line-height: 10px !important;    
 } 
 
#product .sizes input:checked + label{
   border: 3px solid #333;
   background-color: #2fcc71;
   color: #fff;
 }
 
#product .sizes input:checked + label:after {
   content: "\2713";
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   border-radius: 100%;
   border: 2px solid #333;
   background-color: #2fcc71;
   color: #fff;
   z-index: 999;
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   right: -10px;
 }

#product .sizes input {
 display: none;
}
#product .sizes label > input {
   display: inline;
   width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form id="product">
    <section class="sizes">
     <div id="fixedSize"></div>
     <div id="ChooseSize">
      <input type='radio' name='radio_size' id='size1' value='1'><label class='size1-label cell' for='size1'>Standard</label>
      <input type='radio' name='radio_size' id='size2' value='2'><label class='size2-label cell' for='size2'>Different</label>
      <input type='radio' name='radio_size' id='size3' value='3'><label class='size3-label cell' for='size3'>Custom: I would like <input type="size_h"> x <input name="size_w" type="text"></label>
     </div> 
  </section>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the radio inputs to allow css to specifically select those elements only:

```html
<input type='radio' class='radio' ... >
```

```css
#product .sizes input.radio {
    display: none;
}
```

Alternatively, you could give ids to the inputs you want to show and override the css after hiding all inputs:

```html
<input type='radio' name='radio_size' id='size3' value='3'><label class='size3-label cell' for='size3'>Custom: I would like <input id="input-h" type="size_h"> x <input id="input-w" name="size_w" type="text"></label>
```

```css
#input-w, #input-h {
    display: inline;
}
```

```css
#product .sizes label{
   position: relative;
   color: #2fcc71;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   text-align: center;
   height: 80px;
   line-height: 80px; 
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
   border: 3px solid #2fcc71;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
#product .sizes label span{
 display: inline-block !important;
   color: #2fcc71;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: 1rem;
   text-align: left;
   height: 10px !important;
   line-height: 10px !important;    
 } 
 
#product .sizes input:checked + label{
   border: 3px solid #333;
   background-color: #2fcc71;
   color: #fff;
 }
 
#product .sizes input:checked + label:after {
   content: "\2713";
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   border-radius: 100%;
   border: 2px solid #333;
   background-color: #2fcc71;
   color: #fff;
   z-index: 999;
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   right: -10px;
 }

#product .sizes input.radio {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="product">
    <section class="sizes">
     <div id="fixedSize"></div>
     <div id="ChooseSize">
      <input type='radio' class='radio' name='radio_size' id='size1' value='1'><label class='size1-label cell' for='size1'>Standard</label>
      <input type='radio' class='radio' name='radio_size' id='size2' value='2'><label class='size2-label cell' for='size2'>Different</label>
      <input type='radio' class='radio' name='radio_size' id='size3' value='3'><label class='size3-label cell' for='size3'>Custom: I would like <input name="size_h" type="text"> x <input name="size_w" type="text"></label>
     </div> 
  </section>  
</form>
```